# A scatter graph with all vertices meeting at a common vertex

Tags: graph-theory

I have been wanting to find the fairest way to find a meeting place for all my n>2 clients, or vertices. The journey that each client must travel, edge length, must be so that no single client travels more than a small difference than one another, or epsilon.

My algorithm has been to connect the n vertices in the completed external graph with n edges and find the average distance of each edge, mark the distance with a new vertex, connect the new averaged vertices, and replete that process until I have a smaller region where I can find a fair meeting place.

This process works for me for graph that are around the city. I want to find a way that is either more fair or faster than this process since it takes time.

Thank you,

Eric

Comment: As I read your problem, ideally you would fit a circle to the client locations and pick the center as the meeting place for them all.  However in a scatter of locations it may not be possible to achieve the desired tolerance $\epsilon$ of distance variations in this way.  This could lead to asking all clients to travel a very long distance, to even out the relative distances, something that would likely annoy your clients.  Perhaps you can explain more clearly what the objective function for the problem should be.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to make it more fair, you could account for clusters of vertices. As in, don't let one vertex be an outlier that skews your average and try to accommodate for it. Putting weight on close groups of vertices might be good as a way of making things fairer